# Matlab - moving window, avoiding nested loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm trying to write a "weighted moving window" without nested loops for speed improvement.
I already tried using arrayfun without getting exciting results, but maybe I did it in a wrong way.

The window has a different weight in each position (stored in B) and should be superimposed on a matrix A returning the values of the matrix A that lie inside the window, times the weight of the window in that position (read from B).
Also, the windows can overlap one on the other and in this case the maximum value should be kept.
Finally window's dimension and shift should be parameters of the function.

It looks more difficult that it actually is, so I show you the code that I would like to improve:

```
A = reshape([1:35],7,5)';   % values matrix
B = [1:3;4:6];              % window s weight matrix

% matrices size
[m n] = size(A);
[a b] = size(B);

% window s parameters
shift = 2;                  % window s movement at each iteration
zone = 3;                   % window s size (zone x zone)

% preallocation
C = ones(m,n);              % to store the right weight to be applied in each position

% loop through positions and find the best weight when they overlap
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
       C(i,j) = max(max(B( max(round((i-zone)/shift)+1,1) : min(ceil(i/shift),a) , max(round((j-zone)/shift)+1,1) : min(ceil(j/shift),b))));
    end
end

% find the output of the windows
result = C.*A;
```

I hope that I made myself clear, but if you need more details please ask.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What is `zone` and `shift`? Your code as posted won't run unless these two parameters are defined.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to copy and paste those lines. They are parameters that define respectively the dimension of the window (zone x zone) and the shift of the window (i.e.: the movement of the window in each iteration).
I've changed the code, now it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the Image Processing Toolbox, you'll want to check out how to [perform sliding neighborhood operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/f7-12915.html). In particular, I think the function [NLFILTER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/nlfilter.html) can be used to achieve the result you want:

```
A = reshape([1:35],7,5)';  %'# Matrix to be filtered
B = [1:3;4:6];              %# Window weights
result = nlfilter(A,[2 3],@(M) max(M(:).*B(:)));
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer.
Sliding neighborhood operations would be fine for shift=1, but it seems to me that there is no way to select a custom shift.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [im2col.](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/images/ref/im2col.html;jsessionid=y9JhNQpJjHxY0ftTwVVD0SMGhWD007bBkLB6vNQc0QCLVFGQhJ8D!-1082859228)  Assuming your image is j x k, and your window is m x n, you'll get a matrix that is mn x (j-m+1)*(k-n+1).  Then, you can just take every other column.

Example Code:

```
%A = your_image
B = im2col(A, [m n],'sliding');
C = B(:,1:2:end);
```

And there's your sliding window with "shift 2".

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but doesn't solve part of the problem. Should I have a moving window with zone=3 and shift=2 (more generally, this is true for every window with the shift smaller than the zone), one window and the next one would be partially superimposed (i.e.: contain partially the same values). This cannot be accomplished with C = B(:,1:2:end). But is still an interesting way to work on the matrix, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try `filter`.

For example, to do a windowed average, over 5 elements:

```
outdata = filter([ 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 ], 1, indata);
```